# ASP.NET How to kill this session variable instance

Tags: asp.net

Hey I have a session object I just cant seem to destroy or set null again i.e.

this is how it is set

```
If HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") Is Nothing Then
        Instance = New ShoppingCart()
        Instance.Items = New List(Of CartItem)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") = Instance
    Else
        Instance = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart"), ShoppingCart)
    End If
```

And on my logout I have

Session.Abandon()

But when I log in it still remembers how many items i had in my cart from last time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx

See the remarks, can it have anything to do with it?

Your code doesn't show where you fill the session variable and how or where you destroy it. 
Maybe if you post more code i can tell you more.

Comment: Yes but not where you do it in combination with your null check. Besides it could be the code inside a property's get, filling the session variable everytime you access it.